# Can I use "galore" this way?

Tags: word-usage

I am going to make up an example below. Galore means a lot.

(ex) John asks me,"Do you have any disposable forks and spoons at home?"

(1) I reply,"I have a lot of them."

(2) I reply,"I have lots of them."

(3) I reply,"I have them **galore**."

Can I use the word "galore" in (3)?

Comment: You are referring to synonymous terms. Checking a thesaurus is recommended. Kindly check this out: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/a%20lot?s=t :)

Comment: I am not looking for synonyms. I am wondering whether or not I can use "galore" this way. I edited my title.

Comment: (3) is basically OK, but I wouldn't use it with a pronoun. I would say "I have *forks and spoons* galore."

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you are looking for is

> ***something*** galore

Usually you mention the *something* specifically

> I have ***forks and spoons*** *galore*.
>   *I have lots and lots of forks and spoons*
>
> The toy store was full of ***toys*** *galore*.

> Honor Blackman as Bond girl [*Pussy Galore*](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Pussy_Galore_(Honor_Blackman)) in the film *Goldfinger*
>   I'm sure you can figure out what's implied...

[image]

Comment: "...I've got gadgets and gizmos a-plenty
I've got who's-its and what's-its **galore**
You want thing-a-mabobs?
I've got twenty
But who cares? No big deal. I want more..." - Ariel, Little Mermaid